# php base64_encode and glob can not get to work

Tags: php

Have this function that encodes content of images file to base64.

```
function data_uri($file_to_get_contents, $mime) {  
$contents = file_get_contents( '../images/'. $file_to_get_contents );
$base64 = base64_encode($contents);
return ('data:' . $mime . ';base64,' . $base64);
}
```

Actual location (url) of images file is this

```
$val_img = '../images/2014-12-03/13-1-b5780ffc85f5f29d5ce43d1f4e38003f.gif';
```

I need to access echo image using such url (without `.gif`, `.jpg` etc.).

```
$val_img = '../images/2014-12-03/13-1-b5780ffc85f5f29d5ce43d1f4e38003f';
```

Decided to use `glob`. And use code below.

```
$val_img = glob($val_img. '×.*');
```

Tried also

```
$val_img = glob( '×'. $val_img. '*' );
```

With this see empty array

```
echo '<pre>', print_r($val_img, true), '</pre> $val_img <br/>';
```

And with this

```
echo '<img src='. data_uri($val_img , "../images"). ' alt="Image" >';
```

See error like `Warning: file_get_contents(../images/Array) [<a href='function.file-get-contents'>function.file-get-contents</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

Error informs that in this `$contents = file_get_contents( '../images/'. $file_to_get_contents );` line is error.

But seems something incorrect with this `$val_img = glob($val_img. '×.*');`

What would be correct code?

**Here is my code that works**

```
function data_uri($file_to_get_contents, $mime) {  
$contents = file_get_contents( '../images/'. $file_to_get_contents );
$base64 = base64_encode($contents); 
return ('data:' . $mime . ';base64,' . $base64);
}

$val_img = '../images/2014-12-03/13-1-b5780ffc85f5f29d5ce43d1f4e38003f';

$val_img = glob( $val_img. '*' );

echo '<img src='. data_uri($val_img[0] , "../images"). ' alt="Image" >';
```

Comment: What's with the `'x.*'`? Just `"$val_img.*"` should get the right `glob()` results.

Comment: Also, why are you using `glob()` in the first place? Because you don't know the extension? What if there are two images with different extensions?

Comment: Yes, because i do not know extension. And image names would be unique. I call image name without extension. If such name exists, i want to display the image. That is the reason why i use glob

Comment: `glob("$val_img.*")[0]` then :)

Comment: Got error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in`

Comment: Then you should upgrade php to at least 5.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing an array to your function `data_uri`.

`glob` returns an array. That means that `$val_img` is an array, not a string. But you are treating it as a string when you pass it to `data_uri` as the parameter `$file_to_get_contents`. Specifically, you use it as a string in this line:

```
$contents = file_get_contents( '../images/'. $file_to_get_contents );
```

Easiest way to fix this: change your call to `data_uri`, like so:

```
echo '<img src='. data_uri($val_img[0] , "../images"). ' alt="Image" >';
```

Another option is to loop over the array, like this:

```
foreach($val_img as $one_img) {
    echo '<img src='. data_uri($one_img , "../images"). ' alt="Image" >';
}
```

**Edit:** You also have a logic error in your code. There's no need for the `×` character (whatever that is); your file names don't contain one. Just do `$val_img = glob($val_img. '.*');`

---

Side note: I have found that the best way to prevent these kinds of errors is to use a good IDE (I personally prefer PHPStorm) and add PHPDoc blocks to all your functions describing the parameter types. Then, if you try to pass an array when your function expects a string, you will get a warning from the IDE. Catching stuff like this at development time makes for much cleaner code and helps you avoid releasing errors into the wild.

Comment: Can not get it to work. If i print `$val_img` before `glob` i see string as expected. But if print after `glob` then see empty array.

Comment: Why are you adding the `×`? There's no need for the `×` character (whatever that is); your file names don't contain one. Just do `$val_img = glob($val_img. '.*');`

Comment: Finally got solution. Will write in my question below. Thanks for advices